# Issue with Loading, Deleting and then Checking a JavaScript Cookie

Tags: javascript, drupal, redirect, session-cookies, setcookie

On an enrollment page using forms on a Drupal module, I'm having trouble loading a cookie onto a series of pages. The purpose of the cookie is to have it load onto a multistep form, and then delete it when the form's done. On the next page, there is supposed to be a script that detects if the cookie still exists, but if it does it redirects the user back to the form.

The code I have for the form is here...

```
document.cookie = "visited=yes; path=/enrolled/";  

    $("#enroll-now-fifth-step #edit-return").click(function() {     
        document.cookie = "visited=yes; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
    }); 
});
```

And the code for the page that detects the cookie and redirects the page back to the form if it exists is here...

```
document.cookie = "visited=yes; path=/enrolled/";  
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") >= 0) {  
        location.href = "/enrolled/step-2";                         
    } else {
        document.cookie = "visited=yes; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
    }
```

I've been trying constantly for days with no luck. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: If you are setting the cookie right before checking it won't `document.cookie.indexOf("visited") >= 0` ALWAYS be true?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It's the first cookie I created so thanks for taking the time to point out the cause.